# Is it possible to use pandas and/or pyreadstat to read a large SPSS file in chunks, or does an alternative exist?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, spss

I have a SPSS database that I need to open, but it is huge and if opened naively as in the code below, it saturates RAM and eventually crashes.

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    data = pd.read_spss('database.sav')
    print(data)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The equivalent pandas function to read a SAS database allows for the `chunksize` and `iterator` keywords, mapping the file without reading it all into RAM in one shot, but for SPSS this option appears to be missing. Is there another python module that I could use for this task that would allow for mapping of the database without reading it into RAM in its entirety?

Comment: How "huge" is it ? How many variables/cases/datapoints ? I faced similar problems a while ago and abandoned this path :). csv inputs are way more reliable...

Comment: it's a flat DB with about 500,000 rows of ~500 columns each. CSV export will work, I'm just curious if there's a cleaner way to use the native file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using pyreadstat using the generator read_file_in_chunks. Use the parameter chunksize to regulate how many rows should be read on each iteration.

```
import pyreadstat
fpath = 'database.sav'
reader = pyreadstat.read_file_in_chunks(pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat, fpath, chunksize= 10000)

for df, meta in reader:
    print(df) # df will contain 10K rows
    # do some cool calculations here for the chunk
```

Pandas read_spss uses pyreadstat under the hood, but exposes only a subset of options.